# Windows Phone: Deployment Optimization Failed

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to run my WP 7.1 solution on a WP 8.1 device from Visual Studio 2012. The problem is that I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Could someone please provide some assistance?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out one of the developers on the team did the following. He added an invalid character in the 'Conditional compilation symbols' - this caused the entire solution to produce these types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest update to Visual Studio 2012. If you have it already installed, then run the `Repair` option.

Possibly an ancillary update is causing this error; I had the windows phone emulator die after an Azure install and had to `Repair` visual studio to the latest update at the time.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the advice. Will report back with my findings.